# Hive - How to load full html file content to a single hive row?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I hav 1,000 *.html files in HDFS path and I want to create HIVE table whit this files.
But below query give me a '\n' delimited rows rather than full content of the html.

```
> create external table if not exist mydb.myhtmltable (
> body STRING )
> STORED AS TEXTFILE
> LOCATION '/user/hadoop/dataset/refhtml';
```

How can I put full html content into .body field?
I want 1,000 rows from 1,000 html file.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY \789
```

where 789 is the octal representation of the unicode character you want to use.

so:

```
 create external table if not exist mydb.myhtmltable (
 body STRING )
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
 LINES TERMINATED BY \789
 LOCATION '/user/hadoop/dataset/refhtml';
```

Comment: Thank you javadba for your comment. But \789 throws an error like;    FAILED: SemanticException 4:20 LINES TERMINATED BY only supports newline '\n' right now. Error encountered near token ' '\789'' Looks only '\n' is permitted currently.  If you suggest any other hint, please guide me :) Thank you in advance.